# Change class of element in div when div is focused?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

How do change class of an element inside a div when the parent div is focused?

Like when I am active in the

```
<div id="window" class="fenster"><a class="bye"></a></div>
```

The class of A changes to hello?

Comment: what do you mean by 'focused'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by focused you mean mouse is over it and you can use jQuery?

```
$('#window').mouseover(function() {
    $('a.bye', this).removeClass('bye').addClass('hello');
});
```

And if you want to reset the class when you move the mouse out:

```
$('#window').hover(function() {
    $('a.bye, a.hello', this).toggleClass('bye').toggleClass('hello');
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/cPjyB/)

[JSFiddle Example using only javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/cPjyB/1/)

Comment: More like when I have clicked in it, like when you goto a new windows in an operativesystem

Comment: @Jeremy You could change the first example to use .click instead of .mouseover. That might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without jquery:

document.getElementById('window').setAttribute('class', 'newclassname');